# No lenses for the camera

Tags: camera

My version of blender has no lenses. Does anyone know why they might be missing? Here's a screenshot. Thanks.[image]

Answer (score 3):

In your image you are in the *scene* context.

The *Perspective*, *Orthographic*, and *Panoramic* lens options are located in the *Camera* context.

[image]

*Note that this is only available when the camera is selected.*

Comment: Okay, but now the movie camera icon is missing.

Comment: Between the chain and the checkerboard, I now have a wrench, a triangle and a circle. Why do they change?

Comment: The lenses (and camera options) are only available when the camera is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the preset camera lenses and lens settings? Those are under the camera menu.

[image: Camera menu]

Comment: I'm talking about the three lens types including orthographic that should be there, but there is no lens tab.

Comment: As you can see in my screenshot, there is no lens tab.

Comment: @blendyblenderson You should probably be watching some basic UI tutorials about Blender first, before diving into more complex stuff.

Comment: @blendyblenderson you can also start here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender